# URL throwing 403 forbidden

Tags: permissions

`/main` on my server I can't access...

```
drwxrwxr-x  2 nobody ftp  4.0K 2011-01-10 14:41 dbs
-rwxrwxr-x  1 nobody ftp  1.5K 2008-10-01 00:00 help
-rwxrwxr-x  1 nobody ftp   102 2011-01-10 15:19 .htaccess
drwxrwxr-x  3 nobody ftp  4.0K 2011-01-10 14:41 images
drwxrwxr-x 10 nobody ftp  4.0K 2011-01-10 15:43 main
```

in `/main`

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 nobody ftp  15K 2009-09-04 00:00 index.html
```

There is no .htaccess in `/main`, but the `/.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Any ideas why I can't access `/main/index.html`

Comment: Your Apache error log probably contains information that would be helpful in answering this question.

Comment: Nope, nothing there about this problem

Answer (score 1):

Check your firewall. If you use selinux, try to change it in permissive mode. If this resolve the 403 forbidden, you need to change some policies of selinux in order to abtain access to web pages.

Comment: The only thing we have in place is IPTables